# Learning OOP in PHP. Is this the correct way to do this?

Tags: php, oop

I've just started learning to do oop and I just wanted to put the most basic set of code together to make sure I'm understanding things correctly. I wanted to capture a form entry in the $_POST variable and pass it to an object to have it output something back to the browser. No SQL, no Security measures, just proof of understanding.

Here is the form:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <title>SignUp Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
              include_once "class.php";
        } else {
        ?>
             <form method="post" action="signup.php">
                  <label for="name">Enter name below:</label></br>
                  <input type="text" name="name" id="name"></br>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
             </form>
         <?php
         }
          echo $name->processName($_POST['name']); ?>
     </body>
</html>
```

And here is the class:

```
<?php

class Process {

public $entry;

function __construct($entry) {
    $this->entry = $entry;
}

public function processName($entry) {
    return "You entered " . $this->entry . ".";
}

}
$name = new Process($_POST['name']); ?>
```

This is working without error right now but it doesn't seem like I should have to enter the $_POST in the echo statement on the form page and in the object on the class page. Is this correct? Should I instead be collecting that in the $entry property. It's working, but I don't think the execution is correct. Thanks in advance!

Comment: IMHO it is not a good idea to put data members as public. Use getters and setters instead.

Comment: The line `echo $name->processName($_POST['name']);` is executed every time the page is loaded, whether or not the class is included. If class.php is not included, you should get an error, warning or notice, depending on your configuration.

Comment: I'd recommend you checkout laravel.

Comment: @MichaelCalkins wow that escalated quickly! Also this question is tagged OOP so directing OP to laravel is not really a valid comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your right you don't need to enter the $_POST variable into that function, you could change it to this and it would work without entering the post:

```
public function processName() {
    return "You entered " . $this->entry . ".";
}
```

Because right now `processName` function doesn't do anything with the class's public `$entry` variable, it just echoes out what you put in when you call the function.

What you likely want to do instead is:

Change `public $entry;` to `protected $entry;`

Then:

```
public function getEntry() {
    return $this->entry;
}
```

Then in your html, after constructing the class, you can just put this to get the `$entry` variable:

```
echo $name->getEntry();
```

Comment: `s/protected/private`

Comment: @PeeHaa - Might be valid to have it protected. Depends on its usage

Comment: Yes might be valid. But the rule of thumb should be `private` unless `protected` is needed.

Comment: You need to make sure to include the script with class above the html

Answer (score 0):

Coming from Symfony framework background. You could do something right this:

```
<?php
class Process
{
    protected $post_var;
    public function __construct($p)
    {
        $this->post_var = $p;
    }

    public function getData()
    {

        //checking if not post request
        if(count($this->post_var) == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        $result_arr = [];

        //populating $result_arr with $_POST variables
        foreach ($this->post_var as $key => $value) {
            $result_arr[$key] = $value;
        }

        return $result_arr;
    }
}

$process = new Process($_POST);
$data = $process->getdata();
if($data)
{
    echo $data["name"];
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```